# HAProxy + Dovecot + Gluster

Tags: debian, haproxy, dovecot, glusterfs

I'm looking to setup 2 dovecot servers behind HAProxy using gluster for a high-availability solution.  From the reading I've been doing, it seems that dovecot highly suggests the use of the dovecot director when both dovecot servers have access to the same file system.

However - in this case where traffic is routing through HAProxy first, would that even work in this configuration?

Currently, I'm planning to use `balance source` in haproxy to gain affinity.  I have also set `mmap_disable = yes`.

Are there any recommendations on how to best handle this setup?

Thanks!

Comment: To achieve HA with GlusterFS you need a quorum node. https://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/arbiter-volumes-and-quorum/

Comment: My question here is around dovecot and ha with a gluster storage system.  Thanks though for that link.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there would be a difference between the two IMAP servers being directly accessible or via HAProxy. In both cases they form a HA solution with both servers having access to the same file system.

Using HAProxy prevents you from picking the IMAP server yourself while otherwise you could choose which server to use but this does not change the way you have to setup Dovecot or gluster.